# How I change a value of hidden file according which radio selected

Tags: javascript, php, html, symfony

I have in a `file HTML.twig`:

1- a hidden file should take 3 values according which radio selected, one from my database and two others hiden files values the number 10, like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">
```

2- And I have 3 radioBox:

```
<input id="spa-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Spare {{ price.getSparePrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="rep-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Repair{{ price.getRepairPrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="rep-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" value="Test {{ price.getTestPrice }}" type="radio">
```

3- I did a block Javascript in the same file `HTML.Twig`
I created a function to get the value of each radio:

```
{% block javasc %}
<script>
        function valueLt(){
          var spare= document.getElementById('spa-price');
          var repair= document.getElementById('rep-price');
          var test= document.getElementById('tes-price');

          if (repair.checked){ // Should take the value 10
              alert("repair checked");
              //<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">

          } else if (test.checked){ // Should take the value 10
             alert("test checked");
             //<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="10">

          } else {
             alert("spare checked"); // should take the value from DB
            // <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="{{ price.getLt }}">
        }
     </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Can you tell me how I change the value of my hidden file according each radio selected in the function ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name values of the hidden inputs

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" data-id="spare" value="{{ price.getLt }}">
<input type="hidden" name="lt" data-id="repair" value="10">
<input type="hidden" name="lt" data-id="test" value="10">
```

add the following lines to the appropiate if else clauses:

```
document.querySelector("input[data-id='spare']").value = spare.value;
document.querySelector("input[data-id='repair']").value = repair.value;
document.querySelector("input[data-id='test']").value = test.value;
```

I'm introducing unique `data` properties in the hiddens. In this way you can select them using `document.querySelector` and assign the correct value.

You can easily select HTML-elements with `document.querySelector` and `CSS-selectors`

Comment: Thank you for you answer! But excuse me I have one hidden file, just I gived you an example above. And I want change it according 3 radioBow which one selected.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to change the name of your input hidden to be able to select them independently one from the other :

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt-spare" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lt-repair" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="lt-test" value="">
```

I also removed the value since those will be added by the javascript later on.

```
<input id="spa-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" onchange='valueLt();' value="Spare {{ price.getSparePrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="rep-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" onchange='valueLt();' value="Repair{{ price.getRepairPrice }}" type="radio">
<input id="tes-price" name="price" class="w3-radio" onchange='valueLt();' value="Test {{ price.getTestPrice }}" type="radio">
```

I've noticed a mistake in your radios since the two last had the same name you wouldn't be able to distinct them in your JS and I also added a `onchange()` attribute to trigger your function.

```
<script>
        function valueLt(){
          var spare= document.getElementById('spa-price');
          var repair= document.getElementById('rep-price');
          var test= document.getElementById('tes-price');

          var hiddenSpare =   document.getElementsByName("lt-spare");
          var hiddenRepair =   document.getElementsByName("lt-repair");
          var hiddenTest =   document.getElementsByName("lt-test");

          if (repair.checked){ // Should take the value 10
              alert("repair checked");
              hiddenSpare.value = 10;
              hiddenRepair.value = 10;
              hiddenTest.value = repair.value;

          } else if (test.checked){ // Should take the value 10
             alert("test checked");
             hiddenSpare.value = 10;
             hiddenRepair.value = 10;
             hiddenTest.value = test.value;

          } else {
             alert("spare checked"); // should take the value from DB
             hiddenSpare.value = spare.value;
             hiddenRepair.value = 10;
              hiddenTest.value = 10;
            }
        }
     </script>
```

Here we add variables to select your input hidden that are now distincts.
Then in your `if` on top of changing the desired input to the value of his radio we also set the two others to 10.

Comment: Really thank you for your answer! But I'm very sorry because I have just one hidden file, I should change it's value according which radio selected. And your solution is very good just I commented the two lines in javascript these I'm not need for them, the problem now is how to recovre the value from my database ( I get it via this function {{ getLt }}. Like I wrote above {{ price.getLt }} it give me the value from my database. I mean how I change this line "hiddenSpare.value = spare.value;"

Comment: You're welcome, sadly, I'm not that familiar with twig and i'll need to see your PHP to see how you're setting variable properly.

Comment: Sorry I can't introduce the code PHP in the comment and is long a bit. I'm just took "insert into " all the records in my table and I recovered it by the funtion get.

Comment: Since your answer for this question about switching value is resolved i can only encourage you to accept an answer then take a look at this to ask another question about your twig variable : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok :) and if you see any question from me concern a PHP and javascript please answer me, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% block content %}
<input type="hidden" name="lt_filed" id="lt_filed" value="{{ price.getLt }}">

<input type="radio" name="price" value="{{ price.getSparePrice() }}">
<input type="radio" name="price" value="{{ price.getRepairPrice() }}">
<input type="radio" name="price" value="{{ price.getTestPrice() }}">
{% endblock %}

{% block javascript %}
<script>
$(function() {
 $('input[name="price"]').on('change', function() {
  $('#lt_filed').val($(this).val());
  console.log('Val set '+ $('#lt_filed').val());
 });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee for your answer, But I want change the "lt_filed" by this value ="{{ price.getLt }}"> or 10. My problem how I can get this value ="{{ price.getLt }}"> in javascript.

Comment: Did you actually test this answer?  By placing the javascript inside your twig file you are able to parse/place `twig` variables inside javascript. Above snippet will work as is

Comment: Yes I tested it and it work fine thank you, but I want change the field name="lt_filed" by {{ price.getLt }} or 10 not by the value of the radio.

Comment: Why do you event want such a name for an `input`? If you want to add extra information to inputs use the data attribute e.g. `<input data-foo="{{ price.getLt() }}" />`, to access it in jquery, `$('input[data-foo]').data('foo');`